# What are the implication of having multiple document.ready in a script

Tags: jquery

I've been asked to help debug a pretty tattered hunk of jQuery.  I'm finding the the  block contains several occurrences of document.ready -- often different variations of "ready" syntax.

Anyway, besides be horribly disorganized -- is there a code execution impact when several of these events exist on the same page? A negative hit to performance? Or perhaps risk of race conditions or the like?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$%28document%29.ready%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each .ready adds a handler to the list of handlers for the "ready" event.  There is no race condition; they should be called in the order that they are added.

Answer (score 0):

They're executed top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Each document ready block will be run sequentially as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/fVM4x/

Also check out the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/